# Hosting jQuery locally causes animated counter to be off by one number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the below code to have an animated counter that starts animating when the element becomes visible. The animation aspect works fine if I use jQuery via a CDN, but when I download jQuery and include it locally the number it ends up showing is one off from what it should be. For example I set 80000 as a number, and it animates up to 79999.

The following code works fine since I specified jQuery via a CDN, but if a local copy of jQuery is used (even if I save the same version from the CDN), it causes the off by one error.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<div style="background-color: #ADF8E6; width: 100%; height: 800px;">
<h1>Scroll down</h1>
</div>


<div style="background-color:   #ADD8E6; width: 100%">
<h1>Javascript Counter<p><span class="count-digit">80000</span></h1>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function visible(partial) {
    var $t = partial,
        $w = jQuery(window),
        viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
        viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
        _top = $t.offset().top,
        _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
        compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
        compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop) && $t.is(':visible'));

}

$(window).scroll(function(){

  if(visible($('.count-digit')))
    {
      if($('.count-digit').hasClass('counter-loaded')) return;
      $('.count-digit').addClass('counter-loaded');
      
$('.count-digit').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });
});
    }
})

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

It's hard to demonstrate behavior that only occurs offline, but to replicate, downloading the case JS file from the CDN specified in the code and saving as jquery.min.js, and changing the line including jQuery to refer to the local version should show the behavior I am describing.

What is causing this behavior? Why would jQuery running locally affect the computation it does?

Comment: Try either clearing your browser cache or renaming the downloaded file to `jquery-3.5.1.min.js`

Comment: @Phil I tested in different browsers as well as incognito mode, and the jquery file is named `jquery-3.5.1.min.js` on my system.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this locally. Using either the CDN or a local copy resulted in the number ending on `80000`

Comment: @Phil weird, thanks for testing. I guess it's something peculiar to my setup. I'm really curious what could be causing this behavior. I tested in Chrome, IE and Opera and it's the same behavior in all.